# How to create a view by grouping multiple columns?

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g

Maybe the question is a bit vague. I want to create a view or have a query to change this -->

```
012878     123456 Mike                             12345678 Saving                  1234.52
012878     123456 Mike                             22345678 credit                 -1534.52
012878     123456 Mike                             32345678 Home loan            -453234.52
012878     123458 Jean                             11001234 SAVING                  3213.54
012878     123458 Jean                             21001234 Credit                  -120.34
012878     123458 Jean                             31001234 Personal loan         -63121.23
```

To this ---->

```
    012878     123456 Mike          12345678 Saving                  1234.52
                                    22345678 credit                 -1534.52
                                    32345678 Home loan            -453234.52
    012878     123458 Jean          11001234 SAVING                  3213.54
                                    21001234 Credit                  -120.34
                                    31001234 Personal loan         -63121.23
```

I have two tables:

```
SQL> CREATE TABLE Account (
  2          BSB#            CHAR(6)         NOT NULL, /* Bank BSB number    */
  3          Customer#       NUMBER(10)      NOT NULL, /* Customer number    */
  4          Account#        NUMBER(10)      NOT NULL, /* Account number     */
  5          Type            VARCHAR2(20)    NOT NULL, /* Account type       */
  6          Balance         NUMBER(10,2)    NOT NULL, /* Account balance    */
  7          CONSTRAINT WorksOn_PK PRIMARY KEY(BSB#, Account#),
  8          CONSTRAINT WorksOn_FK1 FOREIGN KEY(BSB#, Customer#) REFERENCES Customer(BSB#, Customer#)
  9  )


SQL> CREATE TABLE Customer (
  2          BSB#            CHAR(6)         NOT NULL, /* Bank BSB number    */
  3          Customer#       NUMBER(10)      NOT NULL, /* Customer number    */
  4          Name            VARCHAR2(30)    NOT NULL, /* Customer name      */
  5          DOB             Date,                     /* Date of birth      */
  6          Sex             CHAR,                     /* M-Male, F-Female   */
  7          Address         VARCHAR2(50)    NOT NULL, /* Customer address   */
  8          Phone#          VARCHAR2(15),             /* Phone number       */
  9          CONSTRAINT Project_PK PRIMARY KEY(BSB#, Customer#),
 10          CONSTRAINT Project_FK FOREIGN KEY (BSB#) REFERENCES Bank(BSB#)
 11  );
```

And to produce first view I used this-->

```
create view view_1 AS
select
a.bsb#, a.customer#, c.name, a.account#, a.type, a.balance
from
account a, customer c
where
c.customer# = a.customer# and c.bsb# = a.bsb#
```

Now I want to group it by bsb#, account# and name. In other words, I want to eliminate rows and change them to space or null value.

Comment: Your syntax is clearly Oracle so I removed the mysql and sql-server tags.

Comment: This is normally the type of data manipulation that would be done at the application layer rather than as a view.  Remember, tables and result sets are inherently unordered, so having an empty or `NULL` value in a column is a bad idea if the data is supposed to be imputed from another row.

Comment: What you are trying to do is formatting. It makes no sense within the relational data model, where each row in a table or in a view must stand on its own.

Comment: @dasblinkenlight well I want to format my select to produce such an output from the view I created or I can create another view. The reason I said I create a view is because I wanted to save the format. Now how can I format it to this way?

Answer (score 1):

In case you need this in a report, try to search for a group feature and place some of the fields in group header and the other columns in group details.

Comment: Can you explain little bit more. I exactly need it for a report. Can you show me a simple example

Comment: What kind of reporting tool are you using?

Answer (score 1):

You can use this example as a template and put your own columns / query as a source of data instead of table T:

```
SQL> With t (a, b, c, d, e, f) as (
  2  select '012878',123456,'Mike',12345678,'Saving', 1234.52 from dual union all
  3  select '012878',123456,'Mike',22345678,'credit',-1534.52 from dual union all
  4  select '012878',123456,'Mike',32345678,'Home loan', -453234.52 from dual union all
  5  select '012878',123458,'Jean',11001234,'SAVING', 3213.54 from dual union all
  6  select '012878',123458,'Jean',21001234,'Credit', -120.34 from dual union all
  7  select '012878',123458,'Jean',31001234,'Personal loan', -63121.23 from dual
  8  )
  9  select decode(rn,1,a,null) a, decode(rn,1,b,null) b, decode(rn,1,c,null) c,
 10  d,e,f
 11  from (
 12  select t.*, row_number() over(partition by a,b,c order by d) rn
 13  from t
 14  ) x
 15  order by x.a, x.b, x.c, x.d
 16  /

A               B C             D E                      F                      
------ ---------- ---- ---------- ------------- ----------                      
012878     123456 Mike   12345678 Saving           1234,52                      
                         22345678 credit          -1534,52                      
                         32345678 Home loan     -453234,52                      
012878     123458 Jean   11001234 SAVING           3213,54                      
                         21001234 Credit           -120,34                      
                         31001234 Personal loan  -63121,23
```

Comment: Thanks for you effort, but as already said, this is type of manipulation is not solved at database layer.

Answer (score 0):

I finally solve this by formatting tool in the sql plus. As I said in my question create a view or query because I need this for reporting in sqlplus command line:

```
create view view_4(BSB#, CUSTOMER#, NAME, ACCOUNT, TYPE, BALANCE) AS (
select
 a.bsb#, a.customer#, c.name, a.account#, a.type, a.balance
from
account a
RIGHT OUTER JOIN customer c
ON
c.customer# = a.customer# and c.bsb# = a.bsb#)


BREAK ON BSB# ON CUSTOMER# ON NAME


SELECT BSB#, CUSTOMER#, NAME, TYPE
    FROM VIEW_3
    ORDER BY CUSTOMER#;​
```

And now the result is exactly what I wanted...

Comment: You don't need a view though, you can just run the query under it directly - the SQL*Plus formatting will still be applied. If you need both together then you can put both in a script and run that.

Comment: Still I have problem with this. It will delete bsb number for the second customer!